# Android - Can't add item to top of navigation view menu

Tags: android, android-menu, android-navigationview

According to the documentation, to add an item to a Menu programmatically you use  [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add(int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

By doing `Menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, 0, "item");` I should be able to add an item to the very top of the menu of my navigation view, but despite this, the newly created item would still be added to the bottom. What could be the problem here?

Comment: And how are the rest of the items being added to the menu?

Comment: @Alsparkz check my answer helps you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, 1000, "Item First");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, 500, "Item Second");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, 200, "Item Third");

        return true;
    }
// 200 is lowest 500 in middle  and finally 1000 so the order is like below
```

[image]

Should work for you!

**Note** : If you use both xml and code like below

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, 0, "1000"); //<---- It's 0
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, 500, "500");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, 200, "200");
        return true;
    }
```

and xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
                                      // <----------not Given
        android:title="5000"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/main_item"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="200"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/teams_item"
        android:orderInCategory="800"
        android:title="800"/>
</menu>
```

and if you forget to add `orderInCategory` to an item like in the *5000* one Then those items go in top giving priority to xml (check the example)

[image]

Comment: @Alsparkz what was your problem in that case?

Comment: yes, I thought that by simply setting 0 as the order number, the item would be added to the top of the menu, like with a List

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `android:orderInCategory` to position the menu at the correct place. The higher the `Integer` the top the menu will appear. Provide this `android:orderInCategory` for all the items in your menu and as well when you are adding it.